# why use callback function in javascript when I can invoke directly a function

Tags: javascript, function, callback, invoke

Why use a callback to invoke another function when I can do it directly by invoking it by its name?

// Callback’s approach:

```
function add10(callback){
        setTimeout(function(){
        let a = 10 ;
        callback(a);
    }, 2000)
}

add10(function(nro){
    console.log(nro + 100)
})
```

// Without callback

```
function add10(num){
    setTimeout(function(){
        let a = 10 ;
        func(a);
    }, 2000)
}

function func(num){
    console.log(num + 100)
}

add10(5);
```

-> In both cases i get the same result with the same workflow.

Comment: If you use this in only one context then there is no need to use a callback. But with the callback you can use the same function for many context. Read about functional-programing for more details.

Comment: Here's a question & answer that talks more about the use of callbacks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23882149/are-javascript-callbacks-are-just-anonymous-functions-sent-as-an-argument-in-a-f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: what is a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309321/javascript-what-is-a-callback) or https://stackoverflow.com/q/23882149/5468463

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you want to perform a variety of different tasks after the `setTimeout`? You can't hard-code them all into `add10`. The callback allows you to customize the task.

Comment: Hi Joshua and thanks for your answer. Maybe I'm not understanding what you say but I think that if I want to perform different tasks after the setTimeout it would be the same in both of the cases (with and without callbacks). But what I see is that, as Jeremy said) callbacks are like a sort of themplate (or interface in Java) where I define a signature and then I can give to that method any implementation which allow me reuse the code.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a callback to:

- Decouple the two pieces of code
- Allow code reuse
- Easier testing.

For instance: Lets say that I write a function that calls a back-end API.  I will use a setTimeout to "mock" the backend API call -- but pretend.

```js
function lookupFromDatabase(id, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback({
      name: `Username #${id}`,
      email: `user${id}@xxx.invalid`,
      gold: 0
    });
  }, 2 * 1000);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  lookupFromDatabase(i, (user) => {
    console.log(`Send email to user ${user.email}`);
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  lookupFromDatabase(i, (user) => {
    user.gold += 1000;
    console.log(`Give user ${user.name} a christmas bonus`);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The callbacks allows you to customize the tasks. `Callbacks` are a method to make sure certain code doesn't execute until other code has finished execution. They are often used to continue code execution after an asynchronous operation has completed.